Test of variance component in one-way random effects ANOVA
I have a question regarding the adaptation of the following to the test of single variance components laid out in Raudenbush and Bryk (2002, p. 63-64). The hypothesis is about a single component of the matrix of random effects variances and covariances $\textbf{T}$
$$
H_0:\tau_{qq} =0,
$$
where $\tau_{qq} = \text{Var}(\beta_{qj})$ for coefficient $p$ across $j$ groups or clusters.
Defining $\hat{V}_{qqj} = \hat{\sigma}^{2}(\textbf{X}_{j}^{T} \textbf{X}_{j})^{-1}$ and under the null hypothesis of no variance in a particular $\beta_{q}$:
$$
\beta_{qj} = \gamma_{q0} + \sum_{s = 1}^{S_{q}} \gamma_{qs} W_{sj}
$$
(i.e., no addition of random effect $u_{qj}$), the resulting ratio is distributed as approximately $\chi^{2}$ with $df = J-S_{q}-1$:
$$
\frac{\sum_{j}(\hat{\beta_{qj}} - \hat{\gamma_{q0}} - \sum_{s=1}^{S_{q}}\hat{\gamma_{qs}}W_{sj})^{2}}{\hat{V}_{qqj}} 
$$
Small values are consistent with the null (i.e., reject with large $\chi^{2}$ / small $p$-value).
In the case of the simple one-way ANOVA with random effects, the above reduces to (p. 71):
$$
\frac{\sum_{j} n_j(\bar{Y}_{.j} - \hat{\gamma_{00}})}{\hat{\sigma}^2}
$$
As the model is simply $Y_{ij} = \gamma_{00} + r_{ij}$ under the null (i.e., no random effects).
And now my question!
In multiparameter situations and in general, one can test hypotheses about the structure of $\textbf{T}$ with a likelihood ratio test based on deviances (as covered on p. 64, and on many places on this site). For pedagogical reasons (i.e., to show my students), I'm attempting to implement the $\chi^{2}$ test directly, using output from either lme4 or nlme. The High School and Beyond dataset used for the example is included with nlme, and the book's results are easy to replicate, apart from this, somewhat contrived example. Their software (HLM7) apparently spits the test out.
Just to check, I fit a gls model with an intercept only (predicting math achievement) and computed the likelihood ratio test of that model against one with random intercepts using lme (based on the model deviances). The result is somewhat close, but not as large as the direct $\chi^{2}$ method:
$$
\text{LR-test}: 986.12\\
\chi^{2}\text{ Result from R&B (p. 70)}: 1660.2
$$
I'd love some insight on the divergence between these two tests, as well as a way to compute the one-way anova case using info in an 'lme' or 'merMod' object. I'm stuck on where to obtain the numerator without computing it directly.
